# angular watching date formatted string throws error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In one of my angular 1.x controllers, I have the following `watch` statement

```
 $scope.$watch($scope.someData.timestamp, doSomething);
```

The `timestamp` property is either `null`, `undefined` or a `string` formatted as a timestamp, like **"2016-05-31T09:34:01.61Z"**

When the `watch`statement is executed, I get the following error:

```
angular.js:11655 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'T09' is an unexpected token at column 11 of the expression [2016-05-31T09:34:01.61Z] starting at [T09:34:01.61Z]. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$parse/syntax?p0=T09&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=11&p3=2016-05-31T09%3A34%3A01.61Z&p4=T09%3A34%3A01.61Z
    at https://localhost:44555/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12
    at Parser.throwError (https://localhost:44555/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12070:11)
    at Parser.parse (https://localhost:44555/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12023:12)
    at $parse (https://localhost:44555/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12737:39)
    at Scope.$watch (https://localhost:44555/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13897:19)
    at initialize (https://localhost:44555/app/MyCtrl.js:49:20)
    at new MyCtrl (https://localhost:44555/app/MyCtrl.js:18:9)
    at invoke (https://localhost:44555/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4203:17)
    at Object.instantiate (https://localhost:44555/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4211:27)
    at https://localhost:44555/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8501:28 <ui-view class="ng-scope">
```

To me, it looks like angular is trying to compile and evaluate the property value. But why?

If I change the `watch` statement, using the function syntax instead, everything works as expected:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){return $scope.someData.timestamp; }, doSomething);
```

**Why is the value parsed?**
**How can I prevent the watched property from being parsed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope), the variable name should be inside quotes like this:

```
$scope.$watch('someData.timestamp', function(){...})
```

Comment: alternatively you may use a function $scope.$watch(function() { return variableHere; }, function() { ... })

Comment: Yes, the quotes are doing the trick.  Actually, I just found it my self. Not by reading the docs, but by referencing the fantastic book ['Build your own AngularJs'](http://teropa.info/build-your-own-angular/)

And the explanation is of cause that the `$watch` method is expecting an expression, so when I give it a value, it expects that value to be an expression...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

$scope.$watch(someData.timestamp, doSomething);

You should use $watchCollection for watching object changes, or $watch for watching scope properties.

Comment: I'm watching a single property, so no need for `$watchCollection`. 
And you, as me, are missing the necessary quotes :-)